# Spring integration java config

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, rabbitmq, spring-integration

**EmailQueueListener**

```
@Component
public class EmailQueueListener{

    public String handleMessage(String string) {
        System.out.println("Message printing");  // this was printed several times
        System.out.println(rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert());  //received null here
        return string;
    }
}
```

**configuration**

```
 @Configuration
 public class RabbitMQConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
            new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        RabbitAdmin admin=new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
        admin.declareQueue(queue());
        return admin;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate=new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        rabbitTemplate.setRoutingKey("eventsQueue");
        rabbitTemplate.setQueue("eventsQueue");
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
       return new Queue("eventsQueue");
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(EmailQueueListener listener){
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container=new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory());
        MessageListenerAdapter adapter=new MessageListenerAdapter(listener, "handleMessage");
        container.setMessageListener(adapter);
        container.addQueues(queue());
        return container;
    }

}
```

**Sender**

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("hello");
```

I updated the code basing on what you said. But this is not working. i could not see the message which i printed to the console in Listener method. Is their anything wrong in my configuration

Comment: Why are you calling `rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert()` within your listener - it already has the message. You also don't show how the template is wired into the listener bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option to register any POJO listener:

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer serviceListenerContainer() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory());
    container.setQueues(requestQueue());
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(new PojoListener()));
    return container;
}
```

Where `PojoListener` is:

```
public class PojoListener {

    public String handleMessage(String foo) {
        return foo.toUpperCase();
    }

}
```

For the `MessageListener` implementation you should use `org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter` to extract `Message` `body` and convert it to desired domain object.

Comment: How does the SimpleMessageListenerContainer know which method to execute inside listener class

Comment: M-m-m. You should specify the `defaultListenerMethod` or use `MessageListenerAdapter.ORIGINAL_DEFAULT_LISTENER_METHOD` - `handleMessage` :-)

Comment: Hey, this is not working for me. i updated my question with the changes you said

Comment: I wonder what you can see then... Does your Broker admin show messages in the queue for you? Do you have some logs on the matter in the application? We have `JavaConfigFixedReplyQueueTests` to consider as a sample for such kind of configuration.

Comment: I can see the same message (System.out.println("Message recieved");) in console now. but it is printing the same message continuously until i stop the server. more overif write this statement System.out.println(rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert()); it is giving "null"

Comment: Please, share also your producer code to reproduce from my side

Comment: ??? Why did you accept the answer? Have you found an issue in your code? What was that ?

Comment: I am inserting custom Object into queue but i am using string input in handlemessage method. there lies the mistake